# Problema com upload de arquivos grandes no PHP

Tags: php, apache, upload

Ja setei nas configurações de php do meu site o tamanho limite de upload (`post_max_size` e `upload_max_filesize`). Coloquei 1 Giga por precaução para os testes.

Porém quando tento fazer um upload de um arquivo de 30 megas, na barra de status mostra o progresso do upload e reparei que o browser tenta realizar o upload por duas vezes e depois cai numa página de erro do próprio navegador.

O upload cai sempre em porcentagens diferentes, por isso imagino que não seja problema com limite de espaço. E arquivos de até 5 megas estão sendo carregados normalmente sem erros.

Realizo normalmente uploads por ftp de arquivos maiores.

Isso seria por causa de instabilidade do servidor? Como funciona esse processo e como controla-lo? Tem como eu persistir mais de 2 vezes o upload?

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Respondendo a pergunta, o servidor é apache. E o tempo de erro é 1 minuto. No php info busquei pelo numero 60 (para ver algum timeout de 60 segundos configurado) e troquei todos que encontrei pra mais. O erro persiste.

Segue minhas configurações do php:

```
[PHP]
asp_tags = On
include_path = ".:/usr/share/pear"
ignore_repeated_source = Off
variables_order = "EGPCS"
track_errors = On
output_buffering = 4096
doc_root = 
log_errors = On
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
auto_append_file = 
disable_classes = 
enable_dl = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
user_dir = 
extension_dir = "/usr/lib/php/modules/"
register_argc_argv = On
display_errors = On
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
safe_mode_exec_dir = 
default_socket_timeout = 1000000000
register_globals = On
unserialize_callback_func = 
y2k_compliance = On
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
expose_php = Off
log_errors_max_len = 1024
report_memleaks = On
engine = On
memory_limit = 640000000000M
short_open_tag = On
upload_tmp_dir = /home/storage/0/be/ca/johny2/tmp
max_execution_time = 6000000000000000
safe_mode_include_dir = 
serialize_precision = 100
precision = 14
register_long_arrays = On
safe_mode = Off
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
default_mimetype = "text/html"
disable_functions = 
file_uploads = On
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
max_input_time = 6000000000000
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
safe_mode_gid = Off
auto_prepend_file = 
implicit_flush = Off
allow_url_fopen = On
upload_max_filesize = 1000000000000M
post_max_size = 100000000000000M
```

Comment: Qual é o código do erro do navegador, ou mensagem?

Comment: "Esta página da web não está disponível". A minha pagina php de upload fica na url, mas abre-se uma pagina de erro padrao do navegador.

Comment: Pode ser timeout de execução do script. Já tentou [`set_time_limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)?

Comment: Tentei o set_time_limit mas nao funcionou tambem.

Comment: O servidor é apache ou IIS?

Comment: Você tem certeza de que as configs estão sendo aplicadas? Dá uma olhada no phpinfo(). Existem uma chance de configs definidas no ini estarem sendo sobrescritas em outro lugar (arquivo php ou htaccess).

Comment: Não sei qual o servidor, mas se Apache, dá uma vista de olhos no valor de `LimitRequestBody`. Se o ficheiro exceder esse valor, ele pode estar a ser bloqueado mesmo antes de chegar ao PHP. [Link para a documentação](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody).

Comment: Só para esclarecer, o tamanho de arquivos enviados pelo upload/post do PHP não têm relação com os enviados via FTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indo ao suporte do meu provedor de hospedagem descobri que meu servidor é compartilhado e por isso tinha bloqueios para upload de arquivos maiores. Não era problema da minha configuração.

Answer (score 3):

Configure no seu PHP.ini essas informações:

```
upload_max_filesize 10M
post_max_size 10M
max_input_time 300
max_execution_time 300
```

Depois defina no seu código as constantes:

```php
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Detalhe, sempre verifique pelo phpinfo(); se as informações que você tá definindo no php.ini estão sendo aplicadas, é muito comum definir no php.ini errado.

Depois dessa forma você sobe seu arquivo:

```php
$name = 'arquivogrande.zip';

header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($name));

readfile($name);
exit;
```

Se continuar estourando o tempo, use a função `set_time_limit ( temposegundos)` para aumentar o tempo de execução do PHP.

Isso deve bastar.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve editar em seu arquivo `php.ini` as duas variáveis: `post_max_size` e `upload_max_filesize` no formato de sintaxe padrão do PHP.

Exemplo:

```php
post_max_size = 100M

upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas essas duas variaveis foram as que eu mencionei no inicio da questao e ja estao devidaemnte setadas.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, Tente então: default_socket_timeout

Comment: Tentei, mas nao deu certo.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo, quando acontece algo assim, difícil de identificar, tento cronometrar o tempo, veja o tempo gasto desde o início do upload até o momento em que é interrompido, veja se é o mesmo

Comment: posta o código PHP do upload para visualizarmos como o mesmo é realizado.