# Problemas com upload PHP

Tags: php

Tenho um sistema de upload, onde o cliente publica arquivos PDF no site. Arquivos inferiores a 10MB ocorre tudo bem, mas quando o arquivo é acima de 10MB, o sistema fica em 92% e não faz o upload. Vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Entrei em contato com o servidor e eles informaram que o limite é de 128MB. Fiquei na dúvida, pois se o sistema faz upload de arquivos inferiores a 10MB, por que acima de 10MB ele para em 92% e não gera nenhum erro e nem logs de erro no servidor? Vejam abaixo o código:

**HTML**

```
    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">                       

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="titulo">Título: </label>
                        <input id="titulo" class="form-control" name="Titulo" placeholder="" type="text">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                       <label for="periodo">Período:</label>
                            <div class="input-group col-md-3">                        
                              <input id="periodo" class="form-control" name="PeriodoInicio" placeholder="" type="text" data-inputmask="'mask' : '99/99/9999'">
                              <span class="input-group-addon">à</span> 
                              <input id="periodo" class="form-control" name="PeriodoFinal" placeholder="" type="text" data-inputmask="'mask' : '99/99/9999'">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                             <label for="ano">Ano:</label>
                           </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="ano" class="form-control" name="AnoEdicao" placeholder="Ex.: <?php echo date("Y"); ?>" type="text" maxlength="4" data-inputmask="'mask' : '9999'">
                          </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px">
                       <label for="arquivo">Arquivo:</label>
                        <input type="file" id="arquivo" name="Arquivo" class="form-control" style="cursor: pointer">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                                <div class="progress progress-striped active">
                                        <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%">
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <div align="center">
                        <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i> Salvar</button>
                      </div>
                    </form>

<script>
    $(document).on('submit', 'form', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //Receber os dados
            $form = $(this);        
            var formdata = new FormData($form[0]);

            //Criar a conexao com o servidor
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            //Progresso do Upload
            request.upload.addEventListener('progress', function (e) {
                    var percent = Math.round(e.loaded / e.total * 100);
                    $form.find('.progress-bar').width(percent + '%').html(percent + '%');
            });

            //Upload completo limpar a barra de progresso
            request.addEventListener('load', function(e){
            $form.find('.progress-bar').addClass('progress-bar-success').html('upload completo...');
            //Atualizar a página após o upload completo
            setTimeout("window.open(self.location, '_self');", 1000);
            });

            //Arquivo responsável em fazer o upload da imagem
            request.open('post', 'processar-cadastro-edicoes.php');
            request.send(formdata);
            console.log(formdata);
    });
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
public function cadastrarEdicoes($arquivo,$temp,$titulo,$periodoInicio,$periodoFinal,$anoEdicao){

      $sqlVerificar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"SELECT * FROM pf_edicoes WHERE Titulo = '".$titulo."' AND PeriodoInicio = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$periodoInicio)."' AND PeriodoFinal = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$periodoFinal)."' AND anoEdicao = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$anoEdicao)."';");

      if(mysqli_num_rows($sqlVerificar) > 0){
           $_SESSION["CadastroExistente"] = time() + 3; // Verifica se o arquivo e o período já está cadastrado      
      }else{
        $extensao = pathinfo($arquivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

           if($extensao != "pdf"){
              $_SESSION["ErroExtensao"] = time() + 3; // Verifica se a extensão é pdf
           }else{   
              $antigo = umask(0);
              $criarDiretorio = mkdir("../../arquivos/".$anoEdicao,0777); 
              umask($antigo);
              $diretorio = "../../arquivos/".$anoEdicao;

              list($nomeArquivo,$extensaoArquivo) = explode(".".$extensao,$arquivo);
              $codArquivo = md5(date("d-m-Y H:i:s").$nomeArquivo).".".$extensao;

                if(move_uploaded_file($temp,$diretorio."/".$codArquivo)){
                   $cadArquivo = "arquivos/".$anoEdicao."/".$codArquivo;
                   $sqlCadastrar = mysqli_query($this->conexao,"INSERT INTO pf_edicoes VALUES(null,'0','".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$titulo)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$periodoInicio)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$periodoFinal)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$cadArquivo)."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($this->conexao,$anoEdicao)."')");

                   if(mysqli_affected_rows($this->conexao) > 0){

                      $idEdicao = mysqli_insert_id($this->conexao);
                      mysqli_query($this->conexao,"UPDATE pf_edicoes SET IdCodEdicoes = '".md5(strrev($idEdicao))."' WHERE IdEdicoes = '".$idEdicao."';");

                      $_SESSION["Sucesso"] = time() + 3;
                      return "<script>window.location.href='cadastrar-edicoes.php';</script>";
                   }else{
                      $_SESSION["ErroCadastro"] = time() + 3; // Erro no cadastro
                   }   

                }else{
                   $_SESSION["ErroUpload"] = time() + 3; // Erro no uplado
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Sinceramente não sei onde está o erro. Se é do nosso lado ou do lado do servidor.

Configuração do PHP no servidor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode ser a configuração do php no tamanho do post. [Problema com upload de arquivos grandes no PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/684/91)

Comment: Olá rray. Fiz uma alteração no meu post. Incluí o código completo HMTL e Jquery, e a imagem da configuração PHP no servidor. Confesso que realmente estou na dúvida se o problema é nosso ou do servidor. Se não houver quaisquer erros da nossa parte, retornarei  ao servidor com argumentos para eles verificarem lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O bloqueio pode ser no `post_max_size` ou no `upload_max_filesize`, um detalhe muito importante, depois de editar o [`PHP.INI`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php) ou o [`PHPRC`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.php) é necessário reiniciar o servidor HTTP (e/ou fastcgi se estiver usando algo como algum proxy reverso).

No entanto o Apache também bloqueios para limitar o tamanho do *payload*.

Talvez o Apache ou algum `.htaccess` esteja sendo bloqueado pelo [**`LimitRequestBody`**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) ou então:

- `LimitRequestFields`
- `LimitRequestFieldSize`
- `LimitRequestLine`

Ou pode se qualquer outro problema que só olhando no console do navegador para saber qual falha ocorreu, podendo até ser uma falha em sua rede local.

Se for uma falha na rede local, algo que eu já sofri várias vezes, então não tem como resolver com programação nem com servidores, talvez o melhor seja **mudar totalmente a abordagem**, no caso eu recomendo até mesmo para melhorar o tempo de resposta no servidor quando houver multiplas sessões é que particione o upload usando a API:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

No entanto montar do zero eu entendo que é algo complexo, que exigirá conhecer melhor HTTP e conhecer melhor as apis e comportamentos entre diferentes navegadores, como parece que você já usa jQuery então recomendo uma biblioteca pronta a https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

No link https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads é explicado como particionar, por exemplo:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({maxChunkSize: 1000000}) //Divide de um 1 MB por vez
    .on('fileuploadchunksend', function (e, data) {})
    .on('fileuploadchunkdone', function (e, data) {})
    .on('fileuploadchunkfail', function (e, data) {})
    .on('fileuploadchunkalways', function (e, data) {});
```

Comment: Olá Guilherme. Quando desabilitamos o wi-fi daqui e tentamos diretamente com o wi-fi portátil do meu smartphone, o upload ocorreu com sucesso. O que pode estar ocorrendo isso? Problemas na nossa operadora de wi-fi ou algum impedimento do nosso IP com o servidor? Essa é a primeira vez que passo por isso.

Comment: O problema é que mesmo que seja um problema na rede local outros usuários podem ter o mesmo problema, vou postar uma solução alternativa, talvez seja melhor

Comment: @Fox.11 editei a resposta, veja se esta lib te ajuda

Comment: Oi Guilherme. Certo. Vou testar o Jquery File Upload que você passou. Obrigado.